# Netbeans Debugger stop on events without breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, javafx

I am working on JavaFx technology for a while using Netbeans : 
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 RC (Build 201510012201)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.1 Patch 1
Java: 1.8.0_71
recently the debugger of Netbeans start to stop on any event without breakpoints ! 
I searched on this issue I found this is Bug ?! I am not persuaded on this answer cause I have this case before some years ,as I remember, and I had a solution 
pleeeez help me with your suggestion 
thank you very much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think my problem was there are a lot of breakpoints , so I used 
Window -> Debugging -> Breakpoints , then I delete all breakpoints

Answer (score 7):

In Netbeans 8.2, when I open the Breakpoints tab, then clicked on 'Select breakpoint groups' and select 'No groups', I could see some breakpoints that were hidden.

Comment: This answer was helpful for me.

Comment: Helped me too. I'm using Netbeans 8.2 for Windows.